# ExtJS extending the height of a row in a certain view

Tags: extjs4

I have a certain view where I want to post text so I need the height of the row cells to be bigger than the default. I look up the documentation of ExtJS 4.0 and come up with this:

```
Ext.define('APP.view.CalendarEventsGrid', {
    //extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',//this is the default which is working
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{ 
        viewConfig: {
            height: 50
        }
    }),



    id: 'CalendarEvent',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.*',
        'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',
        'Ext.form.field.Text',
        'Ext.toolbar.TextItem',
    ],

    initComponent: function(){...
```

But this don't do the trick. So could anyone help me with a way to change the height of the row in this exact view?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What I want to do is not changing the height property of the rows in my entire project but just set a custom height property for the view from my example 'view.CalendarEventsGrid'.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what is your exact problem but i assume that you want to pass `height: 50` in the `viewConfig` config option of `Ext.grid.Panel`

every config of the parent class can be passed through the child class so you don't need to instantiate parent class to specify config options (and actually what you tried in the question is not possible at all :))

```
Ext.define('SYMADM.view.CalendarEventsGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    viewConfig: {
        height: 50
    },
```